# VBA excel: copying range cells from multiple workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy 3 columns (always in the range A18:C113) from multiple workbooks, into a single worksheet of another workbook.

There is no error, but something is wrong, because each time it offsets just by 1 row (and not until the last pasted row), so that it overwrites the data pasted from the previous workbook except for the first row.

```
Sub Import()

Dim wkbkorigin As Workbook
Dim originsheet As Worksheet
Dim destsheet As Worksheet
Dim ResultRow As Long
Dim Fname As String
Dim RngDest As Range


    Set destsheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("2017")
    Set RngDest = destsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp) _
                       .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
    Fname = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/*.xlsx")

    'loop through each file in folder (excluding this one)
    Do While Fname <> "" And Fname <> ThisWorkbook.Name

        If Fname <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then

            Set wkbkorigin = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & Fname)
            Set originsheet = wkbkorigin.Worksheets("Sheet")

            With RngDest
                .Range("A1:C96").Value = originsheet.Range("A18:C113").Value

            End With

            wkbkorigin.Close SaveChanges:=False   'close current file
            Set RngDest = RngDest.Offset(1, 0)

        End If

        Fname = Dir()     'get next file
    Loop
End Sub
```

I hope you can help me! Thank you in advance

Comment: You have to change your offset. In this case you can just change it to be a constant value of ~97 since your array size is constant. Another thing to consider would be to find the last row in your column using the find function for future projects where the array isn't a constant size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Set RngDest = RngDest.Offset(1, 0)` should be changed as it now takes the previous `RngDest` value (Range value which is defined before the loop begins) and only add an row offset of 1. Therefore when the code loop it's second time it will only lower your paste range with 1 row.
So if don't have header in your other worksheets, 96 should work:

```
Set RngDest = RngDest.Offset(96, 0)
```

If you have header, then 97 should be your number:

```
Set RngDest = RngDest.Offset(97, 0)
```

Comment: yes! thank you! this worked, maybe do you know how to look for the last row instead of setting the offset? in case in the future I will need it with random number of rows

Comment: `With RngDest

                .Range("B1:D96").Value = originsheet.Range("A18:C113").Value

                .Range("A1:A96").Value = originsheet.Range("C1").Value
            End With`

I was trying to copy cell C1 in each row in A1:A96, and the C1 from the following workbook in the next 96 rows. But nothing happens, any suggestion?

Comment: Your new line needs to be outside the `With RngDest ... End With` (because you already define your range earlier and now you want to paste the values outside your defined range).... 
So I think this should work :) :
`With RngDest .Range("B1:D96").Value = originsheet.Range("A18:C113").Value End With destsheet.Range("A1:A96").Value = originsheet.Range("C1").Value`

Answer (score 0):

The code below will loop through all workbooks in a folder and do whatever you want, just look for 'your code here' and put you specific code right below that end point.

```
Sub Example()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String, Fnum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim ErrorYes As Boolean

    'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
    MyPath = "C:\your_path_here\"

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
    Fnum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        Fnum = Fnum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
        MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
    If Fnum > 0 Then
        For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then



                On Error Resume Next
                With mybook.Worksheets(1)

                ' your code here . . .

                End With


                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    ErrorYes = True
                    Err.Clear
                    'Close mybook without saving
                    mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                Else
                    'Save and close mybook
                    mybook.Close savechanges:=True
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0
            Else
                'Not possible to open the workbook
                ErrorYes = True
            End If

        Next Fnum
    End If

    If ErrorYes = True Then
        MsgBox "There are problems in one or more files, possible problem:" _
             & vbNewLine & "protected workbook/sheet or a sheet/range that not exist"
    End If

    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```